# awk multiple commands and multiple args

Tags: awk, xargs, cut

I'm trying to turn this output:

```
❯ hg branches -T'{node} {branch}\n'
4b0826975cb29da26a6dd13f463241463c43c6a7 maria
5c31751cdb774f8b6337b6f64232b15903530997 default
```

Into these commands:

```
hg bookmark -r 4b0826975cb29da26a6dd13f463241463c43c6a7 maria -f
hg bookmark -r 5c31751cdb774f8b6337b6f64232b15903530997 default -f
```

I tried:

```sh
hg branches -T'{node} {branch}\n' | awk '{hg bookmark -r $1 $2 -f}'
```

But I don't think it did what I wanted.

Basically I want use space to delimit the args, and \n to delimit the commands. Better yet if I can choose different separators so it's less prone to error.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to turn text into *commands*? i.e. execute immediately? Or into another text that looks like commands but is not executed?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, they're commands that I want to execute immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the missing pieces to your template:

```
hg branches -T'hg bookmark -r {node} {branch} -f\n'
```

If you want to run the result, pipe the output to the shell (assuming your branch names don’t contain single quotes):

```
hg branches -T"hg bookmark -r {node} '{branch}' -f\n" | sh
```